# Running C program returns -1.#QNAN0 instead of number stored in floating-point variable

Tags: c, floating-point, nan

Before going on, I'd like to say that this is my first time here and I don't know how things work yet so please pardon any errors on my part.

When compiled,(source code below) everything works fine except for the content of the float disp which is equal to -1.#QNAN0. Any help on this? Thanks in advance. Some parts of the code are not complete like the switch-case structure. Please temporarily that(Unless it affects the result).

The source code for the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float moneyup(float m);


 int main()
{
char name[20];
char x;
int y;
float disp;
int hunger;

printf("\t\t**********************************************\n");
printf("\t\t*                                            *\n");
printf("\t\t*             How To Get Rich Quick!         *\n");
printf("\t\t*                                            *\n");
printf("\t\t**********************************************\n");
printf("\nThis is an experimental command line interface game made by NayNay AKA Nathan\n");
printf("\nPlease pardon the poor user interface.");

for(;;)
{
    printf("\nPlease enter your name(one only)");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("\nThe name you entered is %s. Is this correct? (type y/n for yes or no)\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    x=getchar();

    if(x=='y')                                                  /*This part with the for loop is used to get the name of the*/
    {                                                           /*user and confirm the correctness of that name. If the name is*/
        printf("Okay! Moving on...");                           /*wrong, the user has the option to change it. Bulletproofing used*/
        break;                                                  /*here*/
    }
    else if(x=='n')
    {
        printf("Alright let's try again.");
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Let's try this again.");
        continue;
    }
}
printf("\nOkay %s, Let's get this story started",name);
printf("\n\nOne sad dreary morning, %s got up from sleep and went to the kitchen to get breakfast.");
printf("\nUnfortunately for him his pantry only contained a bunch of cockroaches going at it and laying their eggs everywhere");
printf("\nHe then checked his pockets and pulled out his last 5-dollar bill. That was all he had left,");
printf("\nHe bought a sandwich for $2 and decides to start a business with $3 as capital");
printf("\n\nChoose how to start");
printf("\n1. Begging.");
printf("\n2. Mow lawns.");
printf("\n3. Apply for post of newspaper boy.");
fflush(stdin);
y=getchar();

switch(y)
{
    case '1':
        printf("You begged for 6 hours and got $5.25\n");
        disp=moneyup(5.25);
        printf("You now have $%f\n",disp);
}
return 0;
}

float moneyup(float m)
{
float money;

money=(float)money+m;
return(money);
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` should not be used.

Comment: Money not initialized

Comment: @VidorVistrom That's priceless! :D

Comment: maybe you intended `static float money;`  (which is not very good design but would work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `money` is uninitialized in the function `moneyup` when used in expression

```
money=(float)money+m;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!